# Android Navigation: shared element transitions not working between fragments

Tags: android-fragments, android-animation, android-navigation, shared-element-transition

I followed the instructions [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-animate-transitions).

Here's my code:

```
val navDirections = PostsListFragmentDirections.actionPostsListFragmentToPostDetailFragment(post)
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
   val animationExtras = FragmentNavigatorExtras(
      title to title.transitionName,
      body to body.transitionName
   )
   navigateWithAnimations(navDirections, animationExtras)
} else {
   navigateTo(navDirections)
}
```

`navigateTo` and `navigateWithAnimations` are extensions functions:

```
fun Fragment.navigateTo(navDirections: NavDirections) {
    NavHostFragment.findNavController(this).navigate(navDirections)
}

fun Fragment.navigateWithAnimations(navDirections: NavDirections, extras: Navigator.Extras) {
    NavHostFragment.findNavController(this).navigate(navDirections, extras)
}
```

The code is being executed but the animations are not working.

Here's the nav_graph.xml

```
<fragment
   android:id="@+id/postsListFragment"
   android:name="PostsListFragment"
   android:label="PostsListFragment">
   <action          
      android:id="@+id/action_postsListFragment_to_postDetailFragment"
      app:destination="@id/postDetailFragment">
      <argument
         android:name="post"
         app:argType="Post"
         app:nullable="true"
         android:defaultValue="@null" />
   </action>
</fragment>
<fragment
   android:id="@+id/postDetailFragment"
   android:name="PostDetailsFragment"
   android:label="PostDetailFragment">
   <argument
      android:name="post"
      app:argType="Post"
      app:nullable="true"
      android:defaultValue="@null" />
</fragment>
```

And here's how I'm setting the view into the second (destination fragment):

```
private val args: PostDetailsFragmentArgs by navArgs()

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    args.post?.let { post ->
        tv_title.text = post.title
        tv_body.text = post.title
    }
}
```

In both XML files I have defined:

```
android:transitionName="transition_title"
android:transitionName="transition_body"
```

Comment: Any solution? I am facing the same issue

Comment: What SDK version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Did you establish the sharedElementEnterTransition property in your second fragment? You would have to do something like this in the onCreate method:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    main = requireActivity() as MainActivity
    sharedElementEnterTransition = ChangeBounds().apply {
        duration = 750
        interpolator = AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator()
    }
    sharedElementReturnTransition = ChangeBounds().apply {
        duration = 750
        interpolator = AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator()
    }
}
```

In other words, the receiving fragment needs to know how to deal with shared elements.